# Impinj connect doesn't work in port 8080

Tags: c#, sdk, rfid, reader, octane-sdk

When I connect my impinj to my pc, I can ping it but I can't access to the web page with the port 8080.

The tutorial I used is : https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/202756528-Keyboard-Wedge-with-Speedway-Connect-Software-VIDEO-

Could you tell me how can I access to

```
http://<reader host name>:8080
```

[Edit 1] I use the Speedway Revolution R420

Comment: Did you see the next paragraph in the tutorial,stating:  "For more recent Speedway Connect versions (version 1.0.4 and newer), you need to use the following URL to access the Speedway Connect web UI:

https://<reader host name>"

Comment: @corvairjo it doesn't work, I tried

Answer (score 0):

The Impinj speedway readers actually have MDNS capability enabled by default and we use this to connect directly to them on a laptop via Ethernet.

Plug an Ethernet cable directly from your laptop to the reader and you can access it with http://169.254.1.1 and if you want the Speedway Connect interface, use https... The current version of speedway connect is 2.0.6.

Make sure the Octane firmware is updated also.

Comment: The current version of speedway connect is 5.6.4. And I can't access with http://169.254.1.1

Any other clue ?

Comment: That's actually not a Speedway Connect version number. The current version of Speedway Connect installs on TOP of Octane which is the 5.6.4 you're referencing. Have you downloaded and installed "Speedway Connect" on the reader?

Comment: Also make sure you're connected to the "Ethernet" port and not "Console". Both are RJ45 jacks.

Comment: Hi @clayperez,

I have downloaded and installed Speedway connect 2.0.6.0. and I'm connected to the Ethernet port. But when I do "http://<reader host name>:8080" I still have "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: Are you opening that in your browser? Also, make sure you're using HTTPS